# Иконки не увеличиваются, на устройствах с большим  экраном. Что делать?

Tags: android, java

Закинул в папки drawable иконки: `ldpi-48; mdpi - 64; hdpi - 96; xhdpi - 128; xxhdpi 192`, но при тестировании на различных устройствах размер иконок не меняется. Вот ссылка на исходники http://rghost.ru/56861536 Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуй закинуть по отдельности в каждую папку соответствующие пикчи. там же есть drawable-ldpi drawable-mdpi etc

Comment: Так я же вроде бы так и сделал, или я что то не понимаю??? 
Я просто новичок в android программировании.

Comment: @Frostik если вы раскидали иконки по папкам, как написали, то все верно сделали. система сама возьмет нужные ресурсы.

Comment: Я раскидал иконки по папкам, после сделал apk, но система берёт иконки только из первой папки. Посмотрите пожалуйста мои исходники, скажите что не так.

Answer (score 1):

Модификаторы dpi обозначают плотность экрана, а не размеры.
Мультиэкранность или кросэранность андроид - посмотрите этот вопрос, возможно поможет

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас кнопка `cool_snar.xml` объявлена только в каталоге `drawable-hdpi`. Что не есть совсем верно. Создайте каталог `drawable` и поместите этот xml туда.
2. Туда же переместите ресурсы которые не зависят от разрешения (типа `ic_launcher.png`)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!